# Strip fbclid from URL if exists

Tags: php

I have sample code:

```
$var = $_GET['myurl'];
```

My sample URL

```
https://mydomain/sample/value-2019?fbclid=xxxxxxxxxxxx

or

https://mydomain/sample/value-2019?date=2018&fbclid=xxxxxxxxxxxx


or 

https://mydomain/sample/value-2019?fbclid=xxxxxxxxxxxx&id=10
or

https://mydomain/sample/value-2019?x=xyz


or etc...
```

$_GET['myurl'] - is my actually URL address.

I need to check if the $ var parameter is fbclid - and if so, delete it.

E.g:

from

```
$var = 'https://mydomain/sample/value-2019?date=2018&fbclid=xxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

I want to have:

```
$var = 'https://mydomain/sample/value-2019?date=2018'
```

IMPORTANT:
The fbclid parameter does not always appear, so I first need to check if it is available in my URL.

How to do it?

Comment: Have you noticed anything about what characters are actually in the fbclid? Are they just hexadecimal numbers 0-9 and a-f? Or do they include other characters?

Comment: Sample fbclid=IwAR3423refdsRDz_3b6mUd3423HIpAszb7PvyZKplVsk3gvBNviJIw43Zt4

Comment: hmm...that looks like base64 encoding..

Comment: I do not know. This parameter was add when redirecting from FB

Comment: Yes, I've seen this parameter, too. Really irritating how Facebook adds it to every link from their site. Also irritating that someone has down-voted your question without providing any reason why. I think it's a good question.

Comment: I've provided an answer below. If it solves your problem, an upvote would be nice :D

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php

$urls = array(
        "https://mydomain/sample/value-2019?fbclid=xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "https://mydomain/sample/value-2019?date=2018&fbclid=xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "https://mydomain/sample/value-2019?fbclid=xxxxxxxxxxxx&id=10",
        "https://mydomain/sample/value-2019?x=xyz"
);

function strip_fbclid($url) {
        $patterns = array(
                '/(\?|&)fbclid=[^&]*$/' => '',
                '/\?fbclid=[^&]*&/' => '?',
                '/&fbclid=[^&]*&/' => '&'
        );

        $search = array_keys($patterns);
        $replace = array_values($patterns);

        return preg_replace($search, $replace, $url);
}

foreach($urls as $url) {
        echo "URL: " . $url . "\n";
        echo "REP: " . strip_fbclid($url) . "\n";
}
```

This code could be made more efficient if we didn't define & parse the pattern/search/replace urls every time we run the function, but this should work?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
    $actual_link=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http");
    $actual_link.="://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]";
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value) if($key!='fbclid') {
      if(isset($args)) $args.="&$key=$value";
      else $args="?$key=$value";
    }
    $actual_link.=$args;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do this server side.
Of course it would work only for GET or HEAD, not if request has a body (ie: POST PUT etc...)

Here exemple with nginx (note that this works because `fbclid` is always appended to query string)

```
map $request_uri $redirect_fbclid {
  "~^(.*)(?:[?&]fbclid=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$"  $1;
}

if ( $redirect_fbclid ) {
  return 301 $redirect_fbclid;
}
```

For apache, could be done using mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&|)fbclid=[^&]*(?:&(.*)|)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

S. Imp's answer is good, however:

```
https://mydomain/sample/value-2019?date=2018&amp;fbclid=xxxxxxxxxxxx // beware of &amp;
```

is another type of pattern to be aware of.